# How to keep the flow in the same intent in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using actions on google and dialogflow agent to build a chatbot. I am developing an open ended conversation where the user gives response to a question and then a new question has to be asked.

Here is the code:

```
app.intent('First', (conv) => {
    const ans = conv.parameters.any;
    if(type[0] === 'RATING'){
        if(ans == 1){
            senddata[0] = qstion[0] + ans;
            conv.ask(qstion[1]);
            
        }
        else if(ans == 2){
            senddata[0] = qstion[0] + ans;
            conv.ask(qstion[1]);
        }
        else if(ans == 3){
            senddata[0] = qstion[0] + ans;
            conv.ask(qstion[1]);
        }
        else if(ans == 4){
            senddata[0] = qstion[0] + ans;
            conv.ask(qstion[1]);
        }
        else if(ans == 5){
            senddata[0] = qstion[0] + ans;
            conv.ask(qstion[1]);
        }
        else{
            conv.add('Please give a number between 1 and 5.');
        }
    }
});
```

When a question has been asked the user needs to give the answer from 1 to 5. If the user provides any other answer then they will be prompted with an alert message that 'Please give a number between 1 and 5.' Then the flow needs to be in the 'First' intent itself and it needs to stay there till the user enters the number from 1 to 5. But as I have set the flow in dialogflow that it should go from First to Second. So, even after prompting the message the flow goes to the 'Second' intent.

How do I keep the flow in the 'First' intent itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Intents are supposed to determine *what the user has said* and not *what you do with it* or the conversation flow. So, in general, you would want a single Intent that captures the user giving a rating, and your code would determine what question they were replying to and handle it appropriately.

You may be tempted to use Followup Intents, which use contexts behind the scenes, to manage the flow. This will only make things more of a mess - especially if all your Intents have the same training phrases. Similarly, while you can manage conversation through using input and output [contexts](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-overview), if all your Intents would have the same training phrase, you're making a lot more work for yourself.

Best is to use [Context parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-input-output#output_contexts) that you set to keep track of the current question. You could then have a single "rating" Intent which captures when a user gives a rating, reads which question was being worked with, saves the value against that question, and advances to the next question.

Simplifying your code to remove redundant parts, it might look something like this:

```
app.intent('Rating', (conv) => {

    // Determine what question we're working with
    const questionContext = conv.contexts.get( 'question' );
    const questionNumber = (questionContext && questionContext.parameters['number']) || 0;

    const ans = conv.parameters.any;
    if(type[0] === 'RATING'){
        if( ans >= 1 && ans <= 5 ){
          // Record the rating
          senddata[questionNumber] = qstion[questionNumber] + ans;

          // Set the context for the next question with a long lifespan
          conv.contexts.set( 'question', 99, {
            number: questionNumber+1;
          });

          // Ask the next question
          conv.ask(qstion[questionNumber+1]);

        } else {
          // They didn't answer between 1 and 5, so this is an error
            conv.add('Please give a number between 1 and 5.');

        }
    }
});
```

There are a few other things to note:

- It looks like you're accepting a `@sys.any` type. This can be pretty inefficient, and doesn't really take advantage of what Intents can do. Remember - Intents represent what the user has said.

  - An improvement might be to make that a `@sys.number` entity type, since you know you want a number.
  - Even better might be to create a custom entity type that only has ratings from 1 through 5.
  - In both these cases, you would have a Fallback Intent which is designed to capture things that don't match and reprompt with what you want.
- Since you're building for the Google Assistant, you may wish to look at [Actions Builder](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/builder) which *does* provide conversational flow design using a scene-based approach.

  - Intents still exist - but they more clearly represent what the user has said, and not the state of the conversation.

Comment: When I am entering any number other than 1 to 5 first, it works perfectly. But when I enter a number from 1 to 5 it does not work. The app crashes and says that "No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?"

Comment: When I am using 5 as a response it says: "TypeError: Assignment to constant variable. at app.intent" at code:  conv.contexts.set( 'question', 99, {
            number: questionNumber=1,
          });

Comment: "No response has been set" suggests that, as you note, your code is crashing for some reason. If the reason is due to the line you give in your second comment - then you have a typo in your code (you should be adding one to `quesitonNumber`, not setting it to 1). If you're still having code problems, you may wish to update your question to add what you're doing now, or go ahead and create a whole new question, since it sounds like you figured out how to solve your initial problem.

Comment: but it's not staying in the same intent. If I enter 9 then it prompts to enter from 1 to 5 and when I enter a number from 1 to 5 then it skips the second question and asks the third question, i.e. the 9 is recorded in the 'First' intent and '4' is recorded for the 'Second' intent and then it asks directly the third question

Comment: The system doesn't "stay" in an Intent at all, since Intents aren't state, they're just matching expression. Although what you've done may change other states that cause different Intents to be matched. Since you've accepted this answer, you may wish to create a new question with screen shots of the Intents that you currently have along with the code you're currently using and an example illustrating what is happening and what should be happening.

Comment: Okay, I considered your suggestion of using the fallback intents, can you tell me with this please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003628/how-to-get-the-fallback-response-in-dialogflow

Comment: @Prisoner the erroneous assignment was in your answer, I submitted an edit on it.