# How to get the fallback response in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am building an open ended chatbot using dialogflow and actions-on-google. If the response entered by the user does not fall into any of the training phrases it falls into the followup-fallback intent. But as the user can enter anything in an open-ended conversation, I want to read what the user has entered. How is this possible?

Here is my code:

```
app.intent('First', (conv, {number}) => {

    const rating = number;
    
    if(type[0] === 'RATING'){
        if(rating >= 1 && rating <= 5){
            senddata[0] =  qstion[0] + rating;
            conv.ask(qstion[1]);
        }
        else{
            conv.ask('Please enter a number between 1 and 5');
        }
    }

});
```

What do I write in this followup-fallback intent to read the response:

```
app.intent('First - fallback', (conv) => {

});
```

Following are the intent images:

'First' Intent:

[image]

'First' intent contexts:

[image]

First-fallback intent:

[image]

'Second' intent:

[image]

Comment: Updating your question to include screen shots of the Intents in question can often help us help you figure out any issues.

Answer (score 0):

To get the raw text from the user, you can use the [`query`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/2.13.0/classes/_service_dialogflow_conv_.dialogflowconversation.html#query) attribute in the `conv` object. So you might have a line such as:

```
const userSaid = conv.query;
```